# multi level dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a multi-level dictionary, which is the count of times the token has appeared with a Pos tag.

example:

```
cat/nt     
cat = token. nt = pos tag
```

I have gotten up to here but I'm stuck.

```
import re 

dicts = {}

wds = re.compile('(\w*|\w+\.\w*)([/])(\w+)')

with open('train.txt', 'r') as td:

for lines in td:

m =  wds.finditer(lines)

for mms in m:

dicts[mms.group(1)] = mms.group(3)
```

***content of train.txt file***

```
Pierre/NNP Vinken/NNP ,/, 61/CD years/NNS old/JJ ,/, will/MD join/VB
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? If it is, you may need to fix your indentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your inner for loop:

```
for mms in m:
    token = mms.group(1)
    pos = mms.group(3)
    if token in dicts:
        if pos in dicts[token]:
            dicts[token][pos] += 1
        else:
            dicts[token][pos] = 1
    else:
        dicts[token] = {pos: 1}
```

This checks if we've seen the token at all before, and given that we have, checks if we've seen it as this part of speech before.  If we've seen this combination before, increment its count.  If we've seen the token, but not this POS, default it to a count of 1.  If we've never even seen the token before, add an entry for it with a sub-dict containing this POS at a count of 1.

You could get the same effect with a default dict, but I thought seeing how it worked behind the scenes would be clearer.

EDIT:
To print the resulting dict, try

```
for token in dicts.keys():
    for pos in dicts[token].keys():
        print "%s %s: %s" % (token, pos, dicts[token][pos])
```

Comment: this is the answer i get.  { 'Rudolph': {'NNP': 1},  '1953': {'CD': 1} } which is perfect but how do I get it into this  format Rudolph NNP: 1    Mark Tozzi

Comment: You said you wanted a multi-level dict.  If you want to print it like that, just iterate the outer keys, then each inner key and print both keys and the value.

Comment: I'm so sorry but how do you write this in python. I am still a beginner Mark Tozzi